# Is book of Daniel in haftarah?

Tags: haftarah, daniel-book-of

Does haftarah include any part from the book of Daniel?  If it does, what parsha is that haftarah associated with?

Comment: I don't see Daniel in http://www.tribeuk.com/sites/default/files/Bar%20Mitzvah%20Calendars.pdf or http://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/2011-2020/triennial-haftarot.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DoubleAA says, we only read *haftarot* from the Prophets, not the Writings. There isn't one clear reason for this. For example, the *Baer Heytev* says that the reason is that you will not find a suitable matter there that fits the week's *parsha*, while others give other reasons. Here is an [article](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/sinay/reshitan1-4.htm) in Hebrew about *haftarot* in general, which discusses this issue as well.